# Utilization of get_FOO_display()

Tags: django, django-models

I want to show the human-readable name for the type selected but I
keep getting the stored value.

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'Basic'),
    ('1', 'Full'),
    ('2', 'Intermediate'),
)

class ServiceType(models.Model):
       type = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
       amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

       def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.get_type_display())
```

Comment: Getting the stored value when?

Comment: When the admin shows the unicode object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake, I've changed the tuple values from ('0', 'Basic) to (0, 'Basic') and it worked. I didn't realize that I was saving a char value as an integer value.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have your answer, but as another link, I'd just like to point out James Bennett's thoughts on this:
[Handle choices the right way](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/)

I think it is a pretty convenient way to do things, and removes the 'magic number' aspect of things.  Worth a read IMO, even if you go for a different option.

From his article (quoted in case it disappears):

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    LIVE_STATUS = 1
    DRAFT_STATUS = 2
    HIDDEN_STATUS = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
        (DRAFT_STATUS, 'Draft'),
        (HIDDEN_STATUS, 'Hidden'),
    )
    # ...some other fields here...
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=LIVE_STATUS)
```

Now we can just import the Entry model and query like so:

```
live_entries = Entry.objects.filter(status=Entry.LIVE_STATUS)
draft_entries = Entry.objects.filter(status=Entry.DRAFT_STATUS)
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'll change that. I've followed the blog project of Practical Django Projects and now I remember that code. I guess reading a book code without coding yourself a personal project it's not the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [ChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) instead of IntegerField in your model.  It sounds like you are seeing an input tag with type=text in your admin but want a select tag.  The default widget associated with a IntegerField is TextInput which would explain what you are seeing.

Another option is to write your own admin and explicitly call out that you want type to be a ChoiceField in the admin.  Something like this:

```
class ServiceTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    type = fields.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

admin.site.register(ServiceType, ServiceTypeAdmin)
```

I would personally start by switching the IntegerField to a ChoiceField.  Way less work involved.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem, and couldn't figure out why it works, but if you change the field type to CharField the get_type_display should work fine.

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
  ('B', 'Basic'),
  ('F', 'Full'),
  ('I', 'Intermediate'),
)

class ServiceType(models.Model):
   type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
   amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Trick

use `TypedChoiceField()`

The answer of your questoin lies in using `TypedChoiceField`, not `ChoiceField`.

you are getting type field from a `django form`, using the `cleaned_data` from a `ChoiceField`. The problem with this is that the output from a `ChoiceField` is a string, not an integer. 
if you use `get_type_display()` right after saving the form, u would probably get the value, but when u have try to retrieve the value from the DB, you would get `integer` instead of string(because your are saving type as Integer field), here you wont be able to get value with `get_type_display.`

Having now looked into this, I see that you should have used the `TypedChoiceField`, to ensure that the output from cleaned_data is always an integer or string.

first of all change `IntergerField` to Char field or `SmallIntergetField`.

Hope this helps.

### Code

```
 type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

in forms.py

```
type = TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, required=False, empty_value=0, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

another possibility is that you could use `MODELFORM` and provide the `widgets` for the field.

### Forms.py

```
class abc(forms.Modelform)
    class Meta:
        model = FOO
    widgets = {
                'type': forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, required=False, empty_value=0, choices=TYPE_CHOICES),
```

Answer (score 0):

`type` shadows with an `in-built bulletin`, that's why `get_type_display()` has no effects. Avoid using column names as `type` instead use `service_type` or something else and use `get_service_type_display()` i.e `get_<column_name>_display()`.