# Django foo_display with values()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Lets say I have a django Model shown below

```
 Class Student(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=100);
     status=models.IntegerField()
```

status field will only have values 1,2.
Is there some way I can replace 1,2 with their corresponding display values
say (pass,fail) every time i use them in values() method without iterating further over the queryset.
eg:

something like this

```
Student.objects.values(staus_display_value)
```

so that this returns a value queryset with display values instead of db values

```
[{"name":"jane","status":"pass"},
{"name":"john","status":"fail"}]
```

I know that Model.get_FOO_display() can be used to get display values for individual objects.

Comment: you can use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224964/3033586 and abstract from using numbers in your queryset ... if doesn't help - edit your question, because it's unclear what you want, maybe add queryset where you have problems

Comment: Seems as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674860/django-using-values-and-get-foo-display

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class Student(models.Model):
    X_CHOICES = (
            (1, 'Pass'),
            (2, 'Fail'),
        )
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100);
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=X_CHOICES)

>>>Student.objects.create(name="myname")
>>>s = Student.objects.get(name="myname")
>>>s.get_status_display()
'Pass'
```

Comment: this works well single object.Please look @ my question edit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the following in your model:

```
Class Student(models.Model):
    X_CHOICES = (
            (u'1', u'Pass'),
            (u'2', u'Fail'),
        )
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100);
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=X_CHOICES)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I include these labels in values() method?

Comment: You don not need to call the values, as the default display value will be "pass"/"fail".

Comment: The display values will be either "pass"/"fail" but the values saved in the db will be "1"/"2" i.e depending upon the choices

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.I was saying about obtaining display values in values query set.